# After summarize, reinsert calculated values into original dataframe dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with some duplicate measurements. I'd like to extract those duplicate measurements to `df2`, then calculate their average value, remove the duplicates from the original `df`, and insert the calculated averages back into the original df.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c('01_01','01_01','01_02','01_03','01_04','01_04'),
                 variable_1 = c('a','a','a','a','a','a'),
                 value = c(0.5,0.7,0.8,0.2,1.2,2.2),
                 variable_2 = c('cat','cat','pig','dog','chicken','chicken'),
                 place = c('Australia','Australia','France','Belguim','Germany','Germany'))

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(id,variable_1,place) %>%
  filter(n()==2) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(value = mean(value)) 

df <- df %>%
  group_by(id,variable_1,place) %>%
  filter(n()==1) %>%
  rbind(df2)
```

After pulling out the duplicates and calculating their means using summarise, not all of the columns in `df2` are retained. This means it's not possible to join the dataframes back up without getting NAs for `variable_2`. Is there another way to summarise whilst retaining the structure of the original dataframe? I could obviously add `variable_2` to the group_by function, but in my actual dataset there are dozens of columns, which would be unweildy.

```
  id    variable_1 value variable_2 place    
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    
1 01_02 a            0.8 pig        France   
2 01_03 a            0.2 dog        Belguim  
3 01_01 a            0.6 NA         Australia
4 01_04 a            1.7 NA         Germany
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to get the mean of any group that has more than 1 row, then you don't need to separate out, since nothing will happen to just one row in a group. Here, I add `max` for `variable_2`, so that it only returns one value and so it is retained in the output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(id,variable_1,place) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(value = mean(value), variable_2 = max(variable_2))
```

**Output**

```
  id    variable_1 place     value variable_2
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     
1 01_01 a          Australia   0.6 cat       
2 01_02 a          France      0.8 pig       
3 01_03 a          Belguim     0.2 dog       
4 01_04 a          Germany     1.7 chicken
```

Or if you do want to have it broken up, then you can just add an additional summary for `variable_2`, so that it doesn't get removed.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(id,variable_1,place) %>%
  filter(n()==2) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(value = mean(value), variable_2 = max(variable_2))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(id,variable_1,place) %>%
  filter(n()==1) %>%
  bind_rows(., df2)
```